# Code Signing VS Driver Signing certificates

Tags: c#, nsis, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, driver-signing

I have written a C# program with a Nullsoft installer that I wish to be signed, firstly because it will be downloaded and secondly, because it contains drivers to be installed and it won't work on 64 bit systems otherwise.

Now I've never had to sign my code before, and I have found two seperate references to Code Signing Certificates **and** Driver Signing Certificates.

Are these two seperate things? Or can I use a code signing certificate to sign both my program **and** the driver?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can use the *same* Certificate for signing both of them. But here is a recommondation how to sign both for a one time fee:

Microsoft only allows some of the CAs the ability to create Certificates which are capable to sign drivers. You can find the List of CAs on [this MSDN Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487315.aspx).

My personal recommondation is StartSSL, because it's very cheap and delivers the *same* quality VeriSign or thers would deliver. Signing drivers using StartSSL requires StartSSL Extended Validation. You can find more Information and pricing [here](http://www.startssl.com/?app=40).

(Hint: For that one time fee for validation, you can create ONE CodeSigning-Certificate and a lot of Wildcard SSl Certificates for free!)

Comment: Addition: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487328 document it's possible to use Authenticode Certificates to sign them using SignTool.exe

Comment: Dead link. So I do need two?

Comment: @Grant unwin: According to the [Kernel Root Certificate from StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/certs/sub.class1.client.ca.crt) you just need that in ordner to sign drivers and assemblies the same way using SignTool.